# Chrome extensions: issue with identity.launchWebAuthFlow

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension

I'm tring to login via my own service. This is what I have now:

**manifest.json**

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: 'index.html'
    });
});
```

**index.html** is where all the extension's logic resides. Here I have a function that starts authentication process:

```
function goLogin(callback)
{
    var redirectUrl = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL('receiveToken');

    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        url: 'http://todolist.dev/app_dev.php/login?response_type=token&redirect_url=' + redirectUrl,
        interactive: true
    }, function(redirectUrl) {
        if (!redirectUrl) {
            return;
        }

        // Get an access token from the url and save it in localStorage
        var queryString = decodeURIComponent(redirectUrl.substr(redirectUrl.indexOf('?') + 1));
        var params = queryString.split('&');

        var accessToken = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            params[i] = params[i].split('=');

            if (params[i][0] == 'access_token') {
                accessToken = params[i][1];
                break;
            }
        }

        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);

        callback();
    });
}
```

The problem is that the popup with the service's login page *sometimes* doesn't open or opens and closes automatically with the response that the user didn't approve access. Sometimes when the popup opens and I try to login with wrong credentials several times, the popup closes automatically as well (with the same "you didn't approve access" response). In the backend I don't have any restrictions to a number of login attempts.

In the backend I have a FOSUserBundle with overridden AuthenticationSuccessHandler (it does what the default success handler does + returns an access token).

Comment: The only possible bug I see in your code is that you're re-using the redirectUrl variable name - better would be to have 2 separate variable names.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that's not a problem, I think.